# AngualrJS controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just began to learn AngularJS by following [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM). First part is okay except when it comes to the `controller` part.

My code is as below (it's the same as in the video)

```
<html data-ng-app="">

    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function SimpleController($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [{
                    name: 'Kamal',
                    city: 'York'
                }, {
                    name: 'Sunil',
                    city: 'DC'
                }, {
                    name: 'Malith',
                    city: 'Gotham'
                }];
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">Name :
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
            </br>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter :name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

when I add `data-ng-controller="SimpleController"` it will not working and give the following error in the console.

[image]
[image]

Then when I try to post the question in the SO , [I tried it in JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/xy23ybzp/1/). I added Angular.js and selected `onLoad` and not working. But when I selected `no wrap - in <head>` **it works fine**.

But I can't do that in my local machine so the problem remains as it is.

Can anybody point me to the correct path ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize app:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SimpleController">
<!--         ^^^^^ -->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xy23ybzp/2/

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Check Manual Initialization Section in Docs

Comment: Yeah. It will work in the JSFiddle. Try selecting `onLoad` instead of `no wrap - in <head>` when you select the `angularJS` file. then it wont work. Still the problem remains in my local code.

Comment: what I meant is my JSFiddle code is still working without your modifications. But if I choose `onLoad` then it wont work.

Comment: thank you for the help. After the initialization of the app we need to use that to define our controllers or something. I figured that by another SO question's answer. I got the hint from your answer though.I posted an answer please let me if know I'm doing it correctly there.

Comment: It is working. But i want to know that is it the correct way or not. thank you for the help. your answer pointed me towards solving my problem.

Comment: @prime Yes! The correct way is defining `controller` on app. Otherwise it will create 100s of global function which is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

After getting help from the answers listed here for this question. I got it working. Below is the working code.

```
<html  >
<head>
<script src = "angular.min.js"  ></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("SimpleController",function($scope){
        $scope.customers = [
        {name :'Kamal',city : 'York'},
        {name : 'Sunil',city:'DC'},
        {name : 'Malith',city:'Gotham'}
        ];
    }); 
</script>

  </head>
  <body  >

  <div ng-app="myApp"  data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name : 
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
    </br>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter :name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```